# How to config VSCode to pick an import suggestion if there are several for the same function?

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, drizzle

I have a module which has 2 similar set of functions, eg `integer`.  `integer` is found in `'drizzle-orm/pg-core'` and `'drizzle-orm/mysql-core'`.

When VSCode auto import for me, it always selects `mysql` but I'm using `pg`. Is there a way to configure VSCode to select `pg` instead ?

Thanks !